# How would I send the output of ls to a for loop that assigns arguments to a case statement?

Tags: bash, for-loop

Pseudo code would be

```
for OUTPUT in $(ls -d */)
do
case $OUTPUT in
1 ) $OUTPUT ;;
esac
done
*) echo -e "Oops!!! Please select a valid number";
```

Not sure if this is even possible or if this makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't parse `ls`. Just use the glob:

```
for OUTPUT in */
```

Second, read the section on the `select` command in the `bash` documentation`.